# change text of same element multiple times

Tags: jquery

I need to change the text of an element multiple times, with delays in between the text changes.

I tried this but the text "1111..." and "22222..." is never displayed. It jumps right to the third text "33333.....".

Code:

```
<font id="test" size="7">0000000000000000</font>

$(function() {

  $('#test').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).text('11111111111111111111').fadeIn(500)
      .fadeOut(500)
      .text('2222222222222222').fadeIn(500)
      .fadeOut(500)
      .text('3333333333333333333').fadeIn(500);
  });

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/evg82drL/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `.text()` inside the *second parameter* passed to `fadeOut` or `fadeIn` - it takes a callback that runs once the fade is completed:

```js
$('#test').fadeOut(500, function() {
  const $this = $(this);
  $this.text('11111111111111111111').fadeIn(500)
    .fadeOut(500, () => $this.text('2222222222222222'))
    .fadeIn(500)
    .fadeOut(500, () => $this.text('3333333333333333333'))
    .fadeIn(500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<font id="test" size="7">0000000000000000</font>
```

Comment: Thank you, works fine. I have a follow-up question regarding adding classes and animations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55318709/chaining-fadein-fadeout-animate-wrong-execution-order