# chaining fadeIn, fadeOut, animate, wrong execution order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to programmatically change some text, adding a class, animating it. So far I have this code:

```
.red {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: red;
}

<font id="test" size="7">0000000000000000</font>

$('#test').fadeOut(500, function() {
  const $this = $(this);
  $this.text('11111111111111111111')
      .fadeIn(500)
      .fadeOut(500, () => $this.text('2222222222222222')
          .css("color", "green"))
          .addClass("red")
          .fadeIn(500)
          .animate({'margin-left': '250px'}, {duration: 3000, complete: function(){
                                    $this.fadeOut(200)
                                }
                              })
});
```

Unfortunately, the order seems to be messed up. The class "red" is added to the text "1111111....." instead to the text "222222...." and I don't understand why.

Here the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3nus4wpy/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put *everything* asynchronous (except further fades) that you want to happen on fade inside the fade callback:

```js
$('#test').fadeOut(500, function() {
  const $this = $(this);
  $this.text('11111111111111111111')
    .fadeIn(500)
    .fadeOut(500, () => {
      $this.text('2222222222222222');
      $this
        .css("color", "green")
        .addClass("red")
    })
    .fadeIn(500, () => {
      $this.animate({
        'margin-left': '250px'
      }, {
        duration: 3000,
        complete: function() {
          $this.fadeOut(200)
        }
      });
    });
});
```

```css
.red {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<font id="test" size="7">0000000000000000</font>
```

You can also call `delay` to create a delay before the next chained function runs, eg:

```js
$('#test').fadeOut(500, function() {
  const $this = $(this);
  $this.text('11111111111111111111')
  .fadeIn(500)
  .fadeOut(500, () => {
    $this.text('2222222222222222');
    $this.css("color", "green").addClass("red")
  })
  .fadeIn(500)
  .delay(500)
  .animate({
      'margin-left': '250px'
    }, {
      duration: 3000
  })
  .delay(3000)
  .fadeOut(5500)
});
```

```css
.red {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<font id="test" size="7">0000000000000000</font>
```

Comment: I don't get it. When I need to add more fadein, fadeout functions, where do I place them, in the callback of the animation? This here for example doesn't work:$('#test').fadeOut(500, function() {
  const $this = $(this);
  $this.text('11111111111111111111')
    .fadeIn(500)
    .fadeOut(500, () => {
      $this.text('2222222222222222');
      $this
        .css("color", "green")
        .addClass("red")
    })
    .fadeIn(500, () => {
      $this.animate({
        'margin-left': '250px'
      }, {duration: 3000})
    })
    .fadeOut(5500)
});

Comment: It seems not possible to add another fadein or fadeout after the fadein having the animate() as callback function.

Comment: I need to be able to chain unlimited number of fadeIn, fadeOut, animate. How do I do that?

Comment: Ok, so it was actually wrong to put the animation() function as callback of the second fadeIn(), and I also don't need to use the callback of the animation() function here, right?

Comment: You can use `animate` if it's at the end of a chain, the callback-based syntax will just look annoying if you have to use it in *combination* with `fade` calls, so switching to `delay` is definitely the better option if you have lots of fades and animations to do.